# How can you use a returned result in a new function without using global variables?

Tags: python, return, global-variables

How can you use a returned variable in a new function without using global variables?

```
def f():
  var1 = 5
  var2 = 10
  return var1, var2

def g():
  var3 = var1*var2
  return var3
```

Comment: You need to save the returned variables into something. `var1, var2 = f()` followed by `var3 = var1 * var2`

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
def g():
  var1,var2 = f()
  var3 = var1*var2
  return var3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of `f()` in a variable (or variables) defined in function `g`.
See an example:

```
def f():
    var1 = 5
    var2 = 10
    return var1, var2

def g():
    var1, var2 = f()
    var3 = var1*var2
    return var3
```

Edit: oops it seems the user mknull has responded just before.